# Find longest path between set of nodes in a tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, longest-path

Recently came across a programming question.

Given a tree, can be non-binary, can be a single chain (or linear), with N nodes.

Input will be a set of K nodes, denoted a1,a2....ak.
I'd like to find the longest simple path(s) that start from one of those K nodes and finish at one of those K nodes (different from start nodes).
A logarithmic algorithm depending on N or K should meet the running time requirements (eg: KlogK, KlogN) if needed should be within my desired time limit.

Thank you

Comment: Does it have to hit every node? Can it revisit nodes?

Comment: No, only start and finish at those K nodes. Simple path, cannot revisit nodes. I've fixed the wording

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can try this approach -

1. Run DFS from any node to find the farthest leaf node, lets call it node X.
2. Run another DFS to find the farthest node from X.
3. The path you found in step 2 is the longest path in the tree.

This should work for all trees, not just binary trees.

Comment: This. To elaborate, the algorithm mentioned here finds the longest simple path in any tree. So in your case, you just have to clip off any part of the tree that is 'below' your given k nodes. So first start with your tree, keep removing leaves not in the set `ai`. At this point, all your leaves are in the set given. After this, run the 3 steps above.

Comment: Removing leaves takes O(n) but in the worst case no leaves will be removed. 2 DFS each takes O(n), altogether O(3n) is too slow :(